# My script which was working quit. I am trying to upload an image from my phone and this has stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, upload, uploading

My tale of woe continues, trying to make an app that will allow me to upload pix from my mobile device.  I can do an "after the fact" separate 'page' that will work and add a photo, but I want it all inclusive.  THIS WAS WORKING AND IT JUST QUIT ON ME.  I don't know if I'm going to have much hair left.

My image form tag looks like this:

Photo:  <input type="file\ name="fileToUpload" id=\fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" />

Here it the portion of the javascript that is somehow breaking.  I alerted it to see if the string looks right and it does.  The end of it is sending values to the php script that completes the upload and adds data to my database table.  (All of that is working).  ALSO - this works FINE from a desktop:

function uploadFile() {

```
    var fd = new FormData();

          var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

          for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)

          {

                 var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];

                 fd.append('myFile', file);

          }
          var itemName = document.getElementById('ItemName').value;
          var mccats = document.getElementById('mccats').value;
          var sccats = document.getElementById('sccats').value;
          var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
          var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
          var location = document.getElementById('location').value;
          
          

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        

     xhr.open("POST", "additem.php?action=newitem&item=" + itemName + "&mccats=" + mccats + "&sccats=" + sccats + "&description=" + description + "&notes=" + notes + "&location=" + location);
    
    
    
     xhr.send(fd);

  }
```

I get that there was an error trying to upload my file even though my progress bar shows that it went - 100%.  Then I get the error saying it's bad.

Comment: We'd need exact error messages, not your word for it.

Comment: This is all I get:  function uploadFailed(evt) {
 
There was an error attempting to upload the file.  I can't figure out how to see what is going on with my phone via an inspection or console window since I have no idea how to get there (turned the developer to on for Safari).  So I don't know the true nature of the error.  I believe it is everything to do with my post to my script - which works famously on the desktop but not on the phone.  I tested it with a simpler script that just does the uploads and nothing to the database and that works.